# Следует ли брать в кавычки фразы, написанные прописными буквами?

Tags: кавычки

Следует ли брать в кавычки фразы, написанные прописными буквами? 
Табличка "ВХОД ВОСПРЕЩЕН"

Comment: Зачем прописные буквы?

Comment: Автору захотелось подчеркнуть, что на табличке надпись была написана прописными

Comment: Хорошо, но то, прописные буквы или нет, не влияет на закавычивание.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В таких случаях надпись выступает в качестве названия предмета. Кавычки обязательны:
*Табличка "ВХОД ВОСПРЕЩЕН".

Табличка с надписью "ВХОД ВОСПРЕЩЕН".*

Answer (score 0):

Это именно в лингвистике есть тенденция писать названия слов другим шрифтом, вследствие того, что использовать кавычки приходится слишком часто. Но о использовании прописных букв и речи не идёт. Пример с gramota.ru:
Слово *допушкинский* образовано приставочным способом от прилагательного *пушкинский*.

Написание прописными буквами не является грамматически правильным, чтобы стоять самому по себе. Необходимо писать в кавычках в качестве цитаты того, как именно кто-то написал на табличке.

А написание может быть ещё более нестандартным: *табличка "ВхОд ВоСпРеЩеН"* — нестандартность привлекает внимание к самой надписи.